# svn ldap automatic authorisation

Tags: authentication, svn, ldap

When we decided to move to LDAP auth for SVN I had assumed that authentication & authorisation would be automatic, i.e. if a user is logged into the network, subversion would accept the user as legitimate and not pop up a login dialog, but just get on with life. Unfortunately, so far we have not achieved this.

It causes problems with, amongst other things, my Source Control extranet web application which used to do a user password lookup (not secure) but now must request authorisation.

Should SVN/LDAP work like I had hoped? If so, is there some arcane config item I need to set? What am I missing?

This, I think, is the appropriate .conf [redacted and obfuscated, of course]

```html
#
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE IT WILL BE REGENERATED AUTOMATICALLY BY SUBVERSION EDGE
#
# If you must make a change to the contents of this file then copy and paste the
# content into the httpd.conf file and comment out the Include statement for
# this file. The httpd.conf file is not modified or generated and is safe for
# you to modify.
#
#

Include "F:\csvn\data/conf/ctf_httpd.conf"
<VirtualHost *:18080>
# SSL is off

# Required for SCRIPT_URI/URL in viewvc libs, not just rewrite rules
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit

# Apache will issue sub_req for PATH_INFO on ScriptAlias which
# gives a spurious error message. Setting auth at root level to avoid clogging logs.
<Location />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "CollabNet Subversion Repository"
  AuthBasicProvider file ldap
  AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://192.168.0.249:3268/OU=Technical Staff,OU=DomainUsers,DC=snip,DC=net?samAccountName?sub" "NONE"

  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=subversion,OU=Technical Staff,OU=DomainUsers,DC=snip,DC=net"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "kasd8asdik"
  LDAPReferrals Off


  AuthUserFile "F:\csvn\data/conf/svn_auth_file"

  Require valid-user
</Location>

# Work around authz and SVNListParentPath issue
RedirectMatch ^(/svn)$ $1/
<Location /svn/>   
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath "F:/csvn/data/repositories"
   SVNReposName "CollabNet Subversion Repository"

  <IfModule deflate_module>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </IfModule>
  AuthzSVNAccessFile "F:\csvn\data/conf/svn_access_file"
  SVNPathAuthz short_circuit
  SVNListParentPath On
</Location>


<Directory "F:\csvn\www\viewVC/docroot">
  AllowOverride None
  Options None
</Directory>
<Location /viewvc-static>
  Require all granted
</Location>
Alias /viewvc-static "F:\csvn\www\viewVC/docroot"

ScriptAlias /viewvc "F:\csvn\bin/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi"

<Location /viewvc>
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  SetEnv CSVN_HOME "F:\csvn"
</Location>

</VirtualHost>

#
# auth helper endpoint for use by SvnEdge
#        
<VirtualHost localhost:50123>
  <Location "/">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "CollabNet Subversion Repository"
  AuthBasicProvider file ldap
  AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://192.168.0.249:3268/OU=Technical Staff,OU=DomainUsers,DC=snip,DC=net?samAccountName?sub" "NONE"

  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=subversion,OU=Technical Staff,OU=DomainUsers,DC=snip,DC=net"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "kasd8asdik"
  LDAPReferrals Off


  AuthUserFile "F:\csvn\data/conf/svn_auth_file"


  Require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: JFYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638286/ldap-and-subversion-who-can-access-my-repository http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016735/svn-with-ldap-authentication-not-working

Comment: `AuthBasicProvider file ldap`?! I see in all another snippets AuthBasicProvider ldap` only and `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative  off` as last resort

Comment: file is to allow non-LDAP admin login. I'll try making those changes, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Should SVN/LDAP work like I had hoped?

Yes

> If so, is there some arcane config item I need to set?

Probably

> What am I missing?

Show your full SVN-related location (from Apache, you have use it?!)

Comment: I have edited my question to include what I hope is the file you mean. redacted, of course.